# Insert Div before group of Divs in a parent Div jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to add a div as the first div in a group of child divs in a parent.

```
$('#activitytable:first-child').before('<div></div>');
```

The parent div's ID is activitytable. I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours and have tried multiple methods with no avail. I am trying to add the new div to the top of the others in activitytable.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!
- Chris

Comment: This works... http://jsfiddle.net/Yfhqr/  Though I would use `$('#activitytable').prepend(`

Comment: Thanks kingjiv. It seems that the problem may be related to the fact that all of the child divs were added to the DOM via jQuery. So instead of it prepending to the top of the div it is prepending to the bottom. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Oh hey, now that I look at it again, what you meant to do was `$('#activitytable div:first-child').before('<div></div>');`.  You were actually adding the div before the "parent" div instead of before its first child.  The `:first-child` was being applied to the table not to children of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see here, your solution does not work overly well: http://jsfiddle.net/Yfhqr/2/

```
$('#activitytable').prepend('<div></div>');
```

does though.

Comment: +1. wildrot, the problem is now that the div is being put on the bottom of the collection of div's. I think it may be because the div's before it are appended to the parent div beforehand. What do you think?

Comment: @ChrisB. I doubt that, but would love to take a look at your real code to get to the bottom of this. Would you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I just changed the method of adding the previous div's to "append" from "before" and now the code is prepending the new div's properly. Thank you!